# Progressive Birthday problem

Tags: probability, statistics, birthday

The Birthday Problem is very interesting to me. The more dates you fill up, the lower the chances a date will be outside what has already been seen.

But I do not seem to understand at all how statistics work. Take this small twist to the situation:

*After asking people one after one, what is the probability that the first time two people share the same date will be exactly at the $10^{th}$ person*

**MY UNDERSTANDING**

After asking 2 people: The chance of two people having the same Bday $P(S)=1- P(\overline{S}) \Rightarrow P(\overline{S})=\frac{1}{365}\cdot\frac{1}{365}\cdot365\cdot364$ which is the traditional Bday formula.

But then the situation after asking $3,4 ... n$ people and so on eludes me.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For the first time two people share the same birthday to be at the $10$th person, you need:

- the first $9$ people to have different birthdays, and
- the $10$th person to have the same birthday as one of the previous $9$

Comment: Well, I don't really care about the $10^{th}$, in particular, it was just a tangible goal for understanding. 

My issue really lies with the base cases.

How do you calculate to prob of the 9 previous not having the same Bday.

Comment: @BertrandDom Consider $$\frac{(365)!}{(365 - n)!} \times \frac{1}{(365)^n}.$$  Then consider $$\frac{n}{365}.$$

Comment: @user2661923 Is summation needed here then since $\frac{1}{365^{n}}\operatorname{nPr}\left(365,n\right)$ is simply the complement of the birthday problem formula. How would you go about that I've never delved into this section of permutations.

Comment: @BertrandDom No, in my previous comment, the first line, which has $2$ factors represents the probability that the first $n$ people do not share a birthday.  Experiment with $n \in \{2,3,4,5\}$ to convince yourself that what I am saying is true.

Comment: @BertrandDom Let $E_1$ be the event that the first $9$ do not share a birthday.  Let $E_2$ be the event that the $10$-th person shares a birthday with one of the first $9$ people.  Then the question that you posed is equivalent to asking what the probability is that events $E_1$ and $E_2$ both occur.

Comment: @user2661923 This second one was useful.

Comment: @user2661923 So for a person at the $n^{th}$ position we have 

$\left(\frac{1}{365^{n-1}}\operatorname{nPr}\left(365,n-1\right)\right)\cdot\frac{n-1}{365}$

Graphing this gives an interesting result where the most likely spot is at 20 exactly. Does this seem right to you?

Comment: @BertrandDom Yes, but that is neither here nor there.  Your education is better served manually working out the problem, using your own intuition, for each $n$ in $\{2,3,4,5\}$.  Then, check the results with the formulas that I gave you, to see if the formulas agree with your intuition, for the small values of $n$.

Comment: The most likely first match is indeed at $20$ - [Wikipedia notes this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#First_match) and it is the positive root of $\frac{365(n-1)}{(365-n+1)n}=1$ rounded up